# Why do floating point numbers in c# and python not calculate correctly

Tags: c#, python, floating-point

If we use a double in c# or a float in python, simple calculations using variables of 1 decimal place seem to not be correct. 
In both python and c#, if I perform the calculation 5.2 - 5.1, I get the answer 0.10000000000000053, when it should obviously be 0.1.

Can someone please explain to me why this is?

Also, in c#, we can use the decimal type to avoid this issue. Is there a similar type in python I can use?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html

Comment: "if I perform the calculation 5.2 - 5.1" --> Code did not do "5.2 - 5.1"  Instead it subtracted a number near 5.1 from a number near 5.2.  Not all numbers are exactly representational. 5.1, 5.2 are two of those.